# Pegar somente elementos iguais em uma matriz

Tags: java, matriz, vector

Tenho uma matriz por exemplo:

```
1 4 7
1 3 4 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Tenho que ver os números que se repetem em TODAS as linhas, no exemplo, deveria ser resultado os números: 1 e 4. Pois são eles que repetem em todas as linhas.

```
Vector<Integer> validos = new Vector<Integer>();
int cont = 0;
for (int linha = 0; linha < resultado.length; linha++)
{

    for (int coluna = 0; coluna < resultado.length - 1; coluna++)
    {
        for (int linha2 = (linha + 1); linha2 < resultado.length; linha2++)
        {
            for (int coluna2 = 0; coluna2 < resultado.length - 1; coluna2++)
            {
                if(resultado[linha][coluna] == resultado[linha2][coluna2])
                {
                    cont ++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Onde a matriz é a variável `resultado`, que é um `int[][]`, tentei implementar um `cont` que se houvesse o número em todas as linhas ele então iria valer o número de linhas da matriz, exemplo, 3.

Só que o código não está funcionando.

O objetivo é pegar esses números repetidos e colocar no `Vector validos`

Comment: O três não aparece na primeira linha. :p

Comment: Erro de digitação kk é 1 e 4 no caso

Comment: Certeza renan? Onde ta isso? Porque é estranho, mesmo usando Java8, o Eclipse não mostra ela como deprecated, como alguns métodos do Time, etc.

Comment: @lvcs Não tenho como postar links aqui, estou pelo celular. Mas no Google vc encontra muito sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei bem qual linguagem você escreveu. De todo modo escrevi em C#, você vai saber fazer as adaptações com os nomes de classe `List`, `Vector`, etc.

No final do código, na variável `int[] validos` terá apenas `1, 2, 3`. Como você quer, **mas tive que adicionar o 3 no primeiro nível da matriz porque não existia.**

```
        int[][] vetor = new int[][] {
            new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 7 },
            new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 6, 7 },
            new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
        };

        List<int> validosList = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < vetor[i].Length; j++)
            {
                int numero = vetor[i][j];

                if (validosList.Contains(numero))
                {
                    continue; //Número já validado. Pula essa verificação.
                }

                int contagem = 0;

                for (int k = 0; k < vetor.Length; k++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < vetor[k].Length; l++)
                    {
                        int numeroEmVerificacao = vetor[k][l];

                        if (numero == numeroEmVerificacao)
                        {
                            contagem++;
                            break; //Vai pra próxima linha do array
                        }
                    }                        
                }

                if (contagem == vetor.Length)
                {
                    validosList.Add(numero);
                }

            }
        }

        int[] validos = validosList.ToArray();
```

Comment: A linguagem estava na tag, é java.

Comment: Adaptei para Java, funcionou perfeitamente!